# A question was posted which is admittedly an edited version of an existing closed question.

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

The question https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30784/did-haj-amin-al-husseini-request-nazi-germany-systematically-murder-jewish-peopl was posted, it's an edited version of the closed question [Did Haj Amin al-Husseini tell Hitler to exterminate the Jews?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/did-haj-amin-al-husseini-have-any-influence-on-the-third-reichs-policies-toward). The OP states so in their question:

> This question is a stripped-down version of Did Haj Amin al-Husseini have any influence on the third reich's policies towards the Jews? Unlike that question, this doesn't ask about Nazi Germany's policy towards Jewish people at the time Hitler met the Mufti of Jerusalem or whether the meeting changed that government's policy.

Should this question stay, or closed as a duplicate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has since been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost a word-for-word duplicate of the other question, therefore the community and I have closed it.

Comment: Close as a duplicate of a closed question?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm why not? even closed questions can have dupes...

Answer (score 1):

I think that the question should be closed.

The claim it asks to examine is the same quote by Netanyahu. It reduces the original question to be less about motivation, but I feel that essentially this is the same question, and that the author should have edited the original question first, and only if the edit was rejected by the community, to open a new question.

Comment: I'm happy with the original question being edited, and if re-opened, my question being merged/deleted.

Comment: Since done: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/did-haj-amin-al-husseini-tell-hitler-to-exterminate-the-jews